# Consulta select que omita valores determinados

Tags: sql

Tengo una consulta donde seleccionó todos los valores A,B y C de la tabla "letras"
Pero me gustaría que a la hora de mostrar mis resultados omitiera por ejemplo la B

```
SELECT * FROM letras where !B
```

Como podría en un select discriminar resultados al mostrar en mi tabla?

el ejemplo de la tabla es

```
id, Latra
1,  A
2,  B
3,  C
```

Comment: algo asi SELECT A, C FROM letras

Comment: Depende, ¿Las letras son datos o columnas?

Comment: columnas, ya si quieres filtrar por datos lo haces en el where

Comment: Hola Michael/ NaCl Las letras son datos

Comment: Escribe detalladamente que te piden hacer porque la verdad no veo la luz

Comment: Puedes proveer el esquema de la tabla `letras`?

Comment: Hola , con un gran gusto! el esquema de el ejemplo  de la tabla es muy simple tabla "letras" columna "letra" 3 filas 1, A / 2,B / 3,C. y quiero que al selecionar mis datos de la columna "letra" solo se vea A y Cen un momento o pongo en la pregunta

Comment: y por lo que comentas, lo que no sabes es usar la clausula where en sql? o sea vos queres select * from letras where letra != "B"

Comment: Si ya lo puse en la pregunta la tabla, muchas gracias gbianchi (podrias poner tu respuesta en respuesta para que la pueda valorar? . ayer subi el ejemplo completo de lo que estoy trabajando pero si me sobre sature y me explique creo que algo enredado

Comment: select * from letras where letra <> 'B'

Comment: ¿Para qué base de datos? Por favor, edita la pregunta y añade la etiqueta del motor de base de datos correspondiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo quieres que los datos a mostrar de tu columna "letra" no muestren datos que contengan "b" en su contenido.

Entonces yo lo realizaría con un "not like":

```
  select * from letras where letra not like '%b%'
```

Comment: hola! recien puede ponerlo en practica y le atinaste enorme mente muchas garcias !

Comment: de nada, un abrazo.

Comment: En este ejemplo no es necesario usar el LIKE, es preferible `letra <> 'B'`. El LIKE sería útil si buscas contenidos parciales dentro de la columna y obviamente es más costoso para el servidor. Saludos.

Comment: Patricio, por lo que entendí yo, necesitaba buscar dentro de una cadena de caracteres, pero si el dato se rellena con un carácter, simplemente lo haría con un  `select * from letras where letra !='b'`